# When all commutant (centralizer) subgroups are abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, equivalence-relations

I have seen the following problem in chapter 9 of Abstract Algebra by Dan Saracino:

Let $G$ be a group and for $a,b \in G$ let $a\ R\ b$ mean that $ab=ba$. Must $R$ be an equivalence relation on $G$? If so , prove it; if not, indicate for which groups $R$ is an equivalence relation.

$R$ is not an equivalence relation in general. However, it is an equivalence relation iff all commutant (centralizer) subgroups of $G$ are abelian.

This is because in every group $a\ R\ b$ implies $b\ R\ a$, and always $a\ R\ a$ holds. So we need to see when $a\ R\ b$ and $b\ R\ c$ imply $a\ R\ c$.

Let's say $\bar b= \{ g \in G |\ bg=gb \}$ is the commutant group of b. Now, for every $a$ and $c$, we have $a\ R\ b$ and $b\ R\ c$ iff $a, c \in \bar b$. Therefore, $a\ R\ c$ iff $\bar b$ is abelian.

Now, we can define $R$ as an equivalence relation iff all commutant subgroups of $G$ are abelian.

One special case of these groups is when all proper subgroups are abelian.
Now my questions are:

When are all the proper subgroups abelian?

More generally:

When are all commutant subgroups abelian?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you mean I write the whole question again by myself? I have seen so many posts that rely on pictures without any comments like your comment on this site.

Comment: [Here is an explanation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742) of why you should not rely on images to convey information not present otherwise in your post. In this instance, this is such a small piece of text that the effort required to render it is negligible. I am not responsible for other people not pointing this out; I personally point it out repeatedly whenever I encounter it.

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. You don' mean the commutator group of $b$, you mean the centralizer of $b$. Groups have a single commutator subgroup, i.e. $[G,G] = \langle [g,h] \mid g,h \in G \rangle$, where $[g,h] = g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$ (some people define $[g,h] = ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ but it makes no difference to the definition of $[G,G]$).

Comment: Note: "commutator subgroup" has a technical meaning in Group Theory. It is not how you are using the term. What you call "the commutator subgroup of $b$" is correctly called "the centralizer of $b$ in $G$".

Comment: "All centralizers are abelian" $\neq$ "all proper subgroups are abelian", since the group itself is a centralizer subgroup (of the identity, or more generally of any central element). If the question is, "what nonabelian subgroups have all proper subgroups abelian" then you are looking for the "minimal non-abelian groups".

Comment: I know that is why I mentioned them as a special case.

Comment: If your question is "when are all (proper) subgroups abelian?" then the rest of the post is irrelevant. Again you are looking for the "minimal non-abelian groups" and a search through the literature will give you lots of hits that have nothing to do with this relation. The answer to "all centralizers are abelian" is "if and only if the group is abelian".

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, khashayar, for your edits of your question!!

Comment: It's not true that all proper subgroups being abelian is a special case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $G$ is abelian the relation is an equivalence relation.

When $G$ is not abelian the relation is not an equivalence relation. If it was, note the identity element commutes with all others, so the class of the identity would contain all group elements.

Answer (score 1):

Groups in which all centralizers are abelian are called CA-groups. It is a famous theorem that CA-groups of odd order are soluble. Of course all groups of odd order are soluble, but the CA-group theorem appeared before that result. More information may be found about such groups [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA-group).